# Cannot get input at play.golang.org

Tags: go, io

I tried the following:

https://play.golang.org/p/a7ZLY2mumnI

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    fmt.Print("Enter text: ")
    text, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')
    fmt.Println(text)
}
```

However, the program exits before I can input anything.

Anybody know what I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Go playground does not support interactive programs. It cannot read from `os.Stdin`.

See [this issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/16667) for details.

This is also explained in the "About" section:

> The playground can use most of the standard library, with some
> exceptions. The only communication a playground program has to the
> outside world is by writing to standard output and standard error.

Answer (score 1):

The Go Playground doesn't allow stdin input due to some reasons. But there's a quick hack that you can use:

1. Create an init function
2. Write your input to a file
3. Read the contents of the file to os.Stdin

[Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/57v__ErcMUq)